# How do I do a fork of only part of an svn repository, while tracking upstream?

Tags: svn, branch

I'm looking at an SVN project with "plugin" support, where I want to fork one of the plugins packaged with the project. How do I fork only that subdirectory in the svn tree? I want to be able to merge in later changes to upstream if possible. (I'm guessing this might be so hopelessly impossible that there's no point.). Getting the history would be nice, but is optional.

In particular I'm most comfortable with managing an hg repository, although I've also worked with bzr, git, and darcs.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main SVN conventions as to how organize a repository (note that these are only conventions, it does not have to be done that way):

```
repo_root -
   trunk - Project1
         - Project2
         ...
   branches - 
         - branch1
            - Project1
            - Project2
            ...
         - branch2
            - Project1
            - Project2
            ...
         ...             
   tags - 
         - tag1
            - Project1
            - Project2
            ...
         - tag2
            - Project1
            - Project2
            ...
         ...
```

or:

```
repo_root -
   - Project1
     - trunk -
     - branches -
       - branch1 -
       ...
     - tags -
     ...
   - Project2
   ...
```

If your repository is already organized in the second way and your plugin is a separate project - then you just branch it (`svn copy repo_root/Project/trunk repo_root/Project/new_branch` - insert http, svn, etc. as applicable).

If your repository is organized in the first way, or even in the second way, but your plugin is not a separate project with its own trunk/branches/tags, you can create a branch containing only the plugin: `svn copy --parents repo_root/trunk/[path_prefix]/plugin repo_root/branches/new_branch/[path_prefix]/plugin`.

You then have to take care to merge from trunk (or other branches) to this branch only the changes done to the plugin (e.g. not `svn merge repo_root/trunk ...`, but `svn merge repo_root/trunk/[path_prefix]/plugin ...`).

You should not get more problems than with usual (e.g. complete trunk or branch) SVN branching and merging.

One important note: if the plugin depends on other parts of the project (which is most probably the case) when developing on the branch one will have to maintain a mixed working copy: check out the trunk, cd to the plugin directory, and run `svn switch ^/branches/new_branch/[path_prefix]/plugin`.